# Database table to XML document?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

Basically I have a asp.net that I need to display an XML document (straight xml, with the tree nodes) I have the sql statement which returns the row names and each one of their values.  Just wondering how I should go about doing this?

SQL Server 2008, my query is just a select * from offices, my results is "1","New York","New York City","555-5555" I would like the output to be

```
<item id="1"> 
<state>New York</state> 
<city>New York City</city> 
<phone>555-5555</phone> 
</item>
```

where state/city/phone is the column name, and the value is the value of that column

Comment: What database and what version of that database are you using?? Can you show us the SQL statement and the output? What is your desired XML from that output?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, my query is just a select * from offices, my results is "1","New York","New York City","555-5555"

I would like the output to be
<item id="1">
   <state>New York</state>
   <city>New York City</city>
   <phone>555-5555</phone>
</item>

where state/city/phone is the column name, and the value is the value of that column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select your query into a DataSet:
([Taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz(v=VS.90).aspx))

```
  string queryString = 
      "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
```

Then, you can [write that DataSet to an XML string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz(v=VS.90).aspx):

```
string xmlDS = custDS.GetXml();
```

View the MSDN pages for more options.

Comment: Okay this worked, now I have the table as an xml that looks something like <NewDataSet>\r\n  <officelist>\r\n    <OfficeID>2176</OfficeID>\r\n    <Office>My Office </Office>\r\n    <Region>Toronto</Region>\r\n    <Division>TO </Division>\r\n

How do I get this to a strict xml page where you can open and close the nodes (in IE)

Comment: You could write the string to the Response object: `Response.Clear();   Response.ContentType = "text/xml";  Response.Write(xmlDS.ToString()); Response.End();`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id AS '@id',state,city,phone FROM offices AS item
FOR XML PATH, ROOT('Offices')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass by datatable than a XML